# Android calendar object works only for the first time

Tags: java, android, calendar, instance, alarmmanager

I am working on scheduling notification system in Android with `Calendar` and `AlarmManager`.

I want to fire notification at particular instance. Suppose I have an event added at **9.05 AM**, then I want to fire a reminder at **9.00 AM** (Say 5 mins earlier).

I have some condition checking mechanism to set `AlarmManager` event but I observed that if my condition checking statement returns the `false` values, then even after providing correct input once again, the condition checking always returns `false`.

e.g. If it's **9.00 AM** right now and I set schedule for **9.03 AM** then condition checker returns `false`, which is correct, but then I go back and set the schedule time to **9.15 AM**. Even though the condition checker is returning `false`. Why?

P.S. If I set schedule time **9.15 AM** correctly in first place instead of setting wrong time, then my condition checking statement works as expected.

Here is a code snippet:

```
private Calendar schedule;

public void addScheduleNotificationFireEvent(List<Integer> scheduleList, long timeFromMeetingInSeconds){
    schedule = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"After Instance: " + schedule.getTimeInMillis());
    long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    schedule.setTimeInMillis(currentMillis);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"After setMillis: " + schedule.getTimeInMillis());
    schedule.set(scheduleList.get(0),scheduleList.get(1),scheduleList.get(2),scheduleList.get(3),scheduleList.get(4),0);
    Date scheduleTime = schedule.getTime();
    long testCase = (((scheduleTime.getTime() - NOTIFICATION_FIRE_OFFEST_TIME - timeFromMeetingInSeconds*1000)-currentMillis)/1000);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"TestCase Value: " + Long.toString(testCase));
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"schedtime: " + scheduleTime.getTime());
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"NOTIF_OFF: " + NOTIFICATION_FIRE_OFFEST_TIME);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "TIME_MEETING: " + timeFromMeetingInSeconds*1000);
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"Current millis: " + currentMillis);
    if(testCase > 0) {
        Intent scheduleStepOutIntent = new Intent(mContext, MeetAppNotifierService.class)
                .setAction("com.cyberfox.meetapp.SHOW_SCHEDULED_STEP_OUT_NOTIFICATION");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(mContext,0,scheduleStepOutIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,(scheduleTime.getTime()-NOTIFICATION_FIRE_OFFEST_TIME-timeFromMeetingInSeconds*1000),pi);
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"triggering at: " + testCase);
    }
    else{
        Intent scheduleNotPossible = new Intent("MY_INTENT_HERE");
        mContext.sendBroadcast(scheduleNotPossible);
    }
    schedule.clear();
    schedule = null;
    scheduleTime = null;
}
```

Comment: What is scheduleList?

Comment: Its a list of integers that holds my schedule date and time. List contains 5 ints i.e. year, month, day of month, hour, minute.

Comment: @Pranjal Please [edit] the question and add this information to it (possibly with some sample data, so people can reproduce the problem)

Comment: I switched from default Calendar object to Joda time library.